# Multidimensional array v. Sorting multiple arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've hit a snag in continuing my work in a C++ program, I'm not sure what the best way to approach my problem is. Here is the situation in non-programming terms: I have a list of children and each child has a specific weight, age, and happiness. I have a way that people can visually view the bones of the child that is specific to these characteristics. (Think of an MMO character customization where there are sliders for each characteristic and when you slide the weight slider to heavy, the walk cycle looks like the character is heavier).

Before, my system had a set walk cycle for each end of the spectrum for each characteristic. For example, there is one specific walk cycle for the heaviest walk, one for the lightest walk, one for youngest walk, etc. There was not middle input, the output was the position of the slider on the scale and the heaviest walk cycle and the lightest walk cycle were averaged by a specific percentage, the position of the slider.

Now to the problem, I have a large library of preset walk cycles and each walk cycle has a specific weight, age, and happiness. So, Joe has a weight of 4, an age of 7, and happiness level of 8 and Sally 2, 3, 5. When the sliders move to a the specific value (weight 5, age 8, happiness 7). However, only one slider can be moved at one time and the slider that was moved last is the most important characteristic to find the closest match to. I want to find in my library the child that has the closest to all three of these values and Joe will be the closest.

I was told to check out using a 3 dimensional array but I would rather use an array of child objects and do multiple searches on that array which, I am a rookie and I know the search will take a bit of computing time but I keep leaning towards using the single array. I could also use a two dimensional array but I'm not sure. What data structure would be the best to search for three values in?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

How many different values can each slider take? If there are say ten values for each slider this would mean there are 10*10*10=1000 different possible character classes. If your library has less than 1000 walk cycles just reading through them all looking for the nearest match is probably gonna be fast enough.

Of course if there are 100 values for each slider then you may want something more clever. My point is there are some thing that don't have to be optimized.

Also is your library of walk cycles fixed once and for all? If so perhaps you could pre compute the walk cycle for each setting of the sliders and write that to a static array.

Comment: The sliders are on a 1-10 scale and that is set however, the amount of walk cycles will be changing. The characteristic values for each walk cycle are hard coded and will not change. The library is relatively small at the moment but I do not see the library exceeding 100 at most in the future. 

Thank you for your answer. I know that single array will work now I just wanted to check with someone more experienced if this would cause a future problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Wilf that the number of walk cycles is critical, as even if there are say 100,000 cycles you could easily use a brute-force find-the-maximum over...

```
weight_factor * diff(candidate.weight, target.weight) +
age_factor * diff(candidate.age, target.age) +
happiness_factor * diff(candidate.happiness, target.happiness)
```

...where the factor for the last-moved slider was higher than the others.

For more cycles than that you'd want to limit the search space somewhat, and some indices would be useful, e.g.:

```
map<int, map< int, map<int, vector<Cycle*>> cycles_by_weight_age_happiness;
```

You'd populate that adding a pointer to each walk cycle - characterised by { weight, age, happiness } - to `cycles[rw(weight)][ra(age)][rh(happiness)]`, where each of `rw`, `ra` and `rh` rounded the parameters by whatever granularity you liked (e.g. round weight down to nearest 5kgs, group ages by integer part of log base 1.5 of age, leave happiness alone).  Then to search you evaluate the entries "around" your target { rw(weight), ra(age), rh(happiness) } indices... the further from there you deviate (especially on the last-slider-moved parameter, the less likely you are to find a better fit than you've already seen, so tune to taste.

The above indexing is a refinement of what I think Wilf intended - just using functions to decouple the mapping from value space into vectors in the index.